# RegEx and split camelCase

Tags: regex, split, preg-match-all, camelcasing

I want to get an array of all the words with capital letters that are included in the string. But only if the line begins with "set".

For example:

```
- string "setUserId", result array("User", "Id")
- string "getUserId", result false
```

Without limitation about "set" RegEx look like `/([A-Z][a-z]+)/`

Comment: You can't do it with a match I think because PCRE doesn't support variable repetition in lookbehinds. Instead use @codaddict solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str ='setUserId';                          
$rep_str = preg_replace('/^set/','',$str);
if($str != $rep_str) {
        $array = preg_split('/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/',$rep_str);
        var_dump($array);
}
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/lwQBF)

Also your regex will also work.:

```
$str = 'setUserId';
if(preg_match('/^set/',$str) && preg_match_all('/([A-Z][a-z]*)/',$str,$match)) {
        var_dump($match[1]);                                                    
}
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/iji2k)

Comment: Very nice + 1! Is this possible without replace/split i.e. with match?

Comment: A twin regex. Nice. Thanks! I can't give +2 unfortunately :D

Comment: I was hoping that this operation can be performed by one RegEx.

Comment: In this case, my version:
`$name = 'setUserId';
preg_match_all('/(?:^|[A-Z])[a-z]+/', $name, $matches);

$data = $matches[0];
$prefix = array_shift($data);

if ($prefix == 'set') {
    // work with $data containing array('User', 'Id')
}`